# Chat application using php,ratchet and mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ratchet

I have created a chat application using php ajax and mysql . But got responses from here that it is not a good practice to create a chat app.So I have tried it with ratchet from [here](http://socketo.me/docs/hello-world) and its working fine . But the problem is that I want to add this ratchet chatting feture in my previous script which fetches the name of the users and store their ids and will open a chat  containing the messages with them only.
here's my script:

```js
$ = jQuery;
var currentID = null;
var chatTimer = null;
var oldhtml = "";

function fetch_data() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "select.php",
    method: "POST",
    success: function(data) {
      $('#live_data').html(data);
    }
  });
}

function fetch_chat() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "fetch_chat.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: {
      id: currentID
    },
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data) {
      $("#chatbox").show();
      $('#messages').html(data);
      $("div.area").show();
      if (oldhtml !== data) {
        $('#messages').scrollTop($('#messages')[0].scrollHeight);
      }
      oldhtml = data;
    }
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  fetch_data();
  setInterval(function() {
    fetch_chat();
  }, 500);
  $(document).on('click', '.first_name', function() {
    currentID = $(this).data("id1");
    fetch_chat();
  });
  $("#sub").click(function() {
    var text = $("#text").val();
    $.post('insert_chat.php', {
      id: currentID,
      msg: text
    }, function(data) {
      $("#messages").append(data);
      $("#text").val('');
    });
  });
});
```

I want to apply one to one chat technique so that the ratchet server start working only when a name is clicked to chat.Is it possible to combine my script with the default ratchet script?

Comment: You appear to be using AJAX polling. This may work for a small scale test, if you're looking at making this in to a production system I'd strongly suggest you change that to use WebSockets or Server Sent Events instead

Comment: @Rory Can I use websockets or SSE for the same I have questioned